# Can every real Lie algebra be viewed as a Lie algebra of vector fields defined on some manifold?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I know that for any finite-dimensional Lie algebra $L$ over real there is some matrix Lie group $G$ whose Lie algebra is the given $L$ (Ado theorem), that is, it can be interpreted in the Lie algebra of left invariant vector fields of $G$. More speaking, given any (infinite-dimensional) real Lie algebra $L$ can we find a smooth manifold $M$ with $\mathfrak{X}(M)=L$, where $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the Lie algebra of vector fields of $M$? If not, what is an assumption for $L$ so that it holds?

Comment: You don't need Ado's theorem for the finite dimensional case. The Lie algebra of a Lie group is always the set of left invariant vector fields. Ado's theorem just tells you that you can do it with matrices.

Comment: I want to know whether any Lie algebra can be represented as $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ or not,  unlimited the case of Lie algebras of Lie groups.

Comment: Not quite what you want, but if we enforce Lie group structure, this fails. There is an infinite-dimensional Banach-Lie algebra, which is not integrable (it does not come from a Banach-Lie group), see Example VI.7 in "Infinite-Dimensional Lie Groups" by K.H. Neeb (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/278625784_Infinite-Dimensional_Lie_Groups)

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at the paper. It is interesting.